# How to arrange "string columns" horizontally in python?

Tags: python, string, format

I'm working with strings in python, and I need to format a string to print it so it looks something like this at the end:

```
  32         1      9999      523
+  8    - 3801    + 9999    -  49
----    ------    ------    -----
  40     -3800     19998      474
```

```py
operations = []

for problem in problems:
    parts = problem.split()
    sum_result = str(int(parts[0]) + int(parts[2]))
    sum_width = len(sum_result) + 2
    
    operations.append(f'{parts[0].rjust(sum_width, " ")}\n{parts[1]}{parts[2].rjust(sum_width - 1, " ")}\n{"".ljust(sum_width, "-")}\n{sum_result.rjust(sum_width, " ")}')
```

But that will only result in one list with each formatted sum, now I don't know how I could arrange each sum to be horizontal in a string.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You need to accumulate all of the information you want in the first line, then the second, and so on.  Where are you stuck with that ordering?

Comment: @Prune with what you tell me I see it from a different perspective, I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

You could perform addition and difference for your requirement using python  `format` method as shown below.I have added a looping condition to show on how to handle more than a set of values.

```
def format_add_sub(a, b):
for i in range(a, b):
    print("{:6d}".format(i),end='')
    print('{0: >8}'.format(i))
    print("+{:5d}".format(i+5),end='')
    print('{0: >4}'.format("-"),end = '')
    print('{0: >4}'.format(i+5))
    print("{:6s}".format("------"),end='')
    print('{0: >8}'.format("------"))
    sum = i + (i+5)
    diff = (i+5) - i
    print("{:6d}".format(sum),end='')
    print('{0: >8}'.format(diff))
    print("{:6s}".format("------"),end ='')
    print('{0: >8}'.format("------"))
n1 = int(input("Enter value 01:-\n"))
n2 = int(input("Enter value 02:-\n"))
format_add_sub(n1, n2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I wrote:

print('The even number are ', end='')
for even in range(0, 51, 2):
print(even, end=' ')

And this is his output:

The even number are 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50

TEORY!!!:

So i saw the 0 to 50 just are in horizontal because I put end=' ' after the even(in last line) and to let in the same line
I saw put the end='' in final and this wrote the numbers in same line of print